# Android Image doesn't display on some devices

Tags: android, imageview

Android noob here.

I am using an image in an image view.

> Image Specs: 750x500 PNG 835.36kb

It displays correctly on all device emulators and on the real device during debug. However after release it doesn't appear to show on some devices.

It's image with src 'main22' which is causing the issues.

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated!

I am using the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mattblack.fibreapp.MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/main22"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout6"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="INACTIVE"
            android:id="@+id/qjumpButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:onClick="clickFunction"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Queue Jump"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#e4c353"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/shakeImage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/shake"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WINNER!"
            android:id="@+id/winnerText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 x The Prize"
            android:id="@+id/prizeText"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show at the Bar to Claim before we close."
            android:id="@+id/claimText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NO WIN"
            android:id="@+id/nowinText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Try Again Tomorrow."
            android:id="@+id/tryagainText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0.1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shake Again Tomorrow."
            android:id="@+id/shakeTomorrowText"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout3">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CODE"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="profilePageClick" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIBRE"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#d9bc00" />
    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In which subdirectory below res/ have you put the image? Plain drawable, mipmap, or drawable-<qualifier>?

Comment: drawable - just drawable, I have done some googling is it something to do with different file paths?

Comment: Qualifiers allow you to provide resources in certain variants, for example a hires version of an image might go to drawable-hdpi, whereas a low density version of that same image might go to drawable-ldpi. But plain drawable serves as a fallback, so if you copy ypur image there, it will be used on all devices. As you have done so, unfortunately this should not be the reason for not showing up on some devices. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case the image was very large in size and that was the reason image was not showing on some device. Just reduce the image size and it will work.